# Taking the improper integral of a series term-by-term.

Tags: sequences-and-series, multivariable-calculus, improper-integrals

Suppose I have a function $f$ which appears in some complicated formula in a term that looks like $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x, v)\,\text{d}v$. Basically, I want to write $f$ in a series of functions so I can get rid of the integral. I want the "$x$ part" to be in terms of $\mathcal{P}_{\ell}\big(\tanh(x))$ where $\mathcal{P}_{\ell}$ is a Legendre polynomial. The "$v$ part" is a lot tricker for me. First I thought I would just write something like
$$
f(x, v) = \sum_{\ell = 0}^{\infty}\mathcal{P}_{\ell}\big(\tanh(x)\big) \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}A_{\ell n} v^n,
$$

where $A_{\ell n}$ is some matrix of coefficient to be determined. The issue with this is that obviously you can't just integrate term by term since none of them even converge. My next idea was to just somewhat arbitrarily factor out a Gaussian term and write

$$
f(x, v) = \sum_{\ell = 0}^{\infty}\mathcal{P}_{\ell}\big(\tanh(x)\big) \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}A_{\ell n} e^{-v^2}v^n.
$$

Can you just do that? Now it looks like I can just integrate term-by-term since each one doesn't just blatantly diverge. Also, this is for a numerical application, in practice I would actually be truncating the series at $\ell_{\text{max}}$ and $n_{\text{max}}$ so I guess I want to know if this looks like a valid way to try to approxiamate a function plus the issue of wanting to get rid of that infinite integral.

Comment: Can you, if possible, give a bit more info on the problem behind, what are you trying to solve? Quantum mechanics by any chance? To try to answer the question; "can I do this?" This depends on several things: i) is the basis-set $\{\xi_n(x) = \nu^n e^{-\nu^2}\}_{n=0}^\infty$ complete (depends on what type of function you have in hand). ii) is it practical? If you don't know the constants $A_{ln}$ then you will have to find them by integrating. But if the basis-set is not ortonormal this will be nearly impossible (and this set is not ortonormal)

Comment: Have been looking at this question for a few days and can't understand.
If you are so sure that:
$$
f(x, v) = \sum_{\ell = 0}^{\infty}\mathcal{P}_{\ell}\big(\tanh(x)\big) \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}A_{\ell n} e^{-v^2}v^n.
\qquad \mbox{i.e.} \qquad f(x, v) = \sum_{\ell = 0}^{\infty}\mathcal{P}_{\ell}\big(\tanh(x)\big) g_{\ell}(v)
$$
Why then don't you put:
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x, v)\,\text{d}v =
\sum_{\ell = 0}^{\infty}\mathcal{P}_{\ell}\big(\tanh(x)\big) \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} g_{\ell}(n\Delta)\Delta
$$
Where $\Delta$ is a suitable discretization ?

Comment: @HandeBruijn I'm not sure of anything. Imagine we just have a function $h$ of one variable $x$ and we write it as a power series like $h(x) = \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} a_{n} x^n$. But then, if we had to integrate $h$ on the interval $[-\infty, \infty]$, it wouldn't work since $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x^n\,\text{d}x$ doesn't converge. However, it looks like you can just trivially avoid that problem by writing $h(x) = \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} a_{n} e^{-x^2/2} x^n$, and now all of a sudden the infinite integral works term-by-term. I'm wondering if you're allowed to just do that.

Comment: @Mr.G: Do you really need an explicit form for the $v$-part of $f(x,v)$ or just the integral over $v$ ?

Comment: @HandeBruijn Both, since $f$ appears by itself and in an integral.

Comment: @Mr.G: Then perhaps you can use an _interpolation_ instead of a series expansion. With a linear interpolation, the integral becomes like in a previous comment of mine.